# MySQL Complicated Contacts Table

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, coalesce

I am trying to output a list of contact names with their phone number and email address for a given company.

The problem I am facing is getting it to output a contact based on the following criteria:

Contacts may or may not have a name, email or telephone, but they must have at least one of these to appear in the results.

There can be more than one contact per company.

There can be more than one email address and/or telephone number per contact.

There is a primary flag on contacts, so if there is more than one contact and one of them is primary, it should pick that one instead of the other non-primary one.

I have tried the following for getting the contacts name but with no success:

```
SELECT entity_details.name,
COALESCE(
  (SELECT entity_contacts.name FROM entity_contacts
  WHERE entity_contacts.entityRef = entity_details.id
  ORDER BY entity_contacts.isPrimary = 1),
  (SELECT entity_contacts.name FROM entity_contacts
  WHERE entity_contacts.entityRef = entity_details.id)
)
AS contact
FROM entity_details
WHERE entity_details.ownerRef = ?
```

---

This is the closest thing I can get to but I am unsure of if it's correct or not, and it doesn't prioritise primary contacts, it just selects any and groups on the entityRef to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT
entity_details.name, entity_contacts.name AS contact,
entity_contacts_telephones.tel, entity_contacts_emails.email

FROM entity_details
 LEFT JOIN entity_contacts ON entity_details.id = entity_contacts.entityRef
 LEFT JOIN entity_contacts_telephones ON entity_contacts.id = entity_contacts_telephones.contactRef
 LEFT JOIN entity_contacts_emails ON entity_contacts.id = entity_contacts_emails.contactRef

WHERE entity_details.ownerRef = ?

GROUP BY entity_contacts.entityRef
LIMIT ?, ?
```

---

All tables are Innobd, the ones I am working with are in the above edit. All references etc have indexes on where nesisary.

In entity_details there around about 13000 rows, 12000 in entity_contacts, and a few 1000 in entity_contacts_telephones and entity_contacts_emails.

I thought the following would work but it doesn't:

```
LEFT JOIN entity_contacts_telephones
  ON entity_contacts.id = entity_contacts_telephones.contactRef
  AND COALESCE(entity_contacts_telephones.isPrimary = 1, 0)
```

Comment: How many can an entity have in the `details` table? How many do you want to show?

Comment: entity_details are companies, I only want to show one contact (preferably the primary one) per line. Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work (not sure mainly because it's not clear how many rows per entity you can have in each table):

```
SELECT 
    entity_details.name,
    ( SELECT entity_contacts.name 
      FROM entity_contacts
      WHERE entity_contacts.entityRef = entity_details.id
      ORDER BY entity_contacts.isPrimary DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS contact
FROM entity_details
WHERE entity_details.ownerRef = ?
```

---

You probably need a join - of the `[greatest-n-per-group]` type:

```
SELECT 
    d.name,
    ...
    c.whatever
    ...
FROM 
    entity_details AS d
  JOIN
    entity_contacts AS c
      ON  c.PK =                    --- the PRIMARY KEY of contacts table
          ( SELECT cc.PK
            FROM entity_contacts AS cc
            WHERE cc.entityRef = d.id
            ORDER BY cc.isPrimary DESC
            LIMIT 1
           ) 
WHERE d.ownerRef = ?
```

An index on `(entityRef, isPrimary)` would help improving peformance.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this previously but couldn't figure out how to now join the other two tables (telephones and emails) onto it. I couldn't work out how to link them to the selected contact from the query above? Those other tables connect to contacts via a column called contactRef.

Comment: Really I need the id of that contact from above available to the whole SQL query if you know what I mean.

Comment: One entity can have many contacts, a contact can only belong to one entity, but a contact can have many telephone numbers and email addresses. The query takes a very long time to run (about 20 seconds), so I imagine it will take even longer when telephone #s and emails are brought into the mix :(

Comment: Have tried this, but it is also very slow:

SELECT        entity_details.name, contactT.name AS contact
         FROM entity_details
         LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT entity_contacts.*
           FROM entity_contacts
           ORDER BY entity_contacts.isPrimary DESC
         ) AS contactT ON entity_details.id = contactT.entityRef
         WHERE entity_details.ownerRef = ?

Comment: Are your tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: 20 seconds? Do you have any indexes on the tables? How many rows do the tables have? Can you add the answers (and the tables' definitions) in your question?

Comment: Not both, you need a compound (composite) index.